# AngularJS modal json injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of rows that contain data from my json. I want to click a link in each row that will open a modal and display the json data from that specific row. How can I inject the json into the form after the modal is loaded?

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/IrIt4G7HzAoi4uh7euVu?p=preview

EG: If link for ID 1 is clicked, populate input with Code 1.

EG: If link for ID 2 is clicked, populate input with Code 2.

json:

```
[
  {
  "site_id": "ID 1",
  "site_code": "Code 1"
  },
  {
  "site_id": "ID 2",
  "site_code": "Code 2"
  }
]
```

I can bind the correct json into the form if it is on the same page.

```
<a href="" data-ng-click="linkToSite(site)">
  {{site.site_id}}
</a>
```

I can open a modal, but I need a way to inject the json into the form.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open modal, map corresponding site_id</button>
```

Comment: do you want to do something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/ysoJdQLbbZtocYpKfMp6?p=preview

Comment: Yes! I guess I needed another point of view. Been too close to this. Thanks for the simple answer.